# How do I make the Sass Importer combine files into one stylesheet?

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp

I recently found out about this feature in node-sass named [importer](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#importer--v200---experimental), which allows you to handle any encounter with `@import` in your sass files.

I want to take advantage of this feature to import .css files from a npm package easily, similarly to Browserify.

Here's my sass file. (index.scss)

```
@import "normalize.css";
```

When I run this file through Sass and my importer, it should output this (supposed index.css):

```
/*! normalize.css v3.0.3 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */

/**
 * 1. Set default font family to sans-serif.
 * 2. Prevent iOS and IE text size adjust after device orientation change,
 *    without disabling user zoom.
 */

html {
  ...
```

Instead, it outputs this (actual index.css):

```
@import url(/Users/me/workspace/project/node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css);
```

What gives? Why is it that my importer only changes the file path instead of [taking the file and combining it with the original file](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-5)?

Here's my importer and gulp task that runs sass (gulpfile.babel.js):

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
import sass from 'gulp-sass';
import rename from 'gulp-rename';
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
let aliases = {};

function importNpmModule(url, file, done) {

  // check if the path was already found and cached
  if (aliases[url]) {
    return done({ file: aliases[url] });
  }

  // look for modules installed through npm
  try {
    const basePath = path.resolve('node_modules', url);
    const pkgInfo = path.join(basePath, 'package.json');
    const info = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(pkgInfo));
    const newPath = path.join(basePath, info.style);

    aliases[url] = newPath; // cache this request
    return done({ file: newPath });
  } catch(e) {

    // If module could not be found, return the original url
    aliases[url] = url;
    return done({ file:url });
  }
}

gulp.task('sassify', () => {
  return gulp.src('./index.scss')
    .pipe(sass({ importer: inportNpmModule }))
    .pipe(rename('index.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
});
```

EDIT: I also tried using an npm package named sass-module-importer, but it has the exact same problem that I have.

Answer (score 0):

It's not your importer problem. You have this error because there is `.css` in Sass import. Just omit it.

If you have problems after that may be you should update to last version of `node-sass` or use some hacks like [rename `.css` to `.scss` before compiling](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/556#issuecomment-51716735).